# No Internet in Docker Container When Launched with Docker Compose

Tags: docker

The following command starts the container and it can access the Internet:

```
docker run --rm \
-e PLUGIN_BUCKET=the-bucket \
-e PLUGIN_SOURCE=/ \
-e PLUGIN_TARGET=/mnt/data/google \
-e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_FILE=/mnt/key/cred.json \
--mount type=bind,source=/home/ec2-user/data/google,target=/mnt/data/google \
--mount type=bind,source=/home/ec2-user,target=/mnt/data \
 gcs-sync
```

The following docker compose file will start the same container but the sync will fail because there is no Internet:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  gcs_sync:
    image: gcs-sync:latest
    container_name: gcs_sync
    environment:
      PLUGIN_BUCKET: the-bucket
      PLUGIN_SOURCE: /
      PLUGIN_TARGET: /mnt/data/google
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_FILE: /mnt/key/cred.json
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /home/ec2-user/data/google
        target: /mnt/tdata/google
      - type: bind
        source: /home/ec2-user/key
        target: /mnt/key
```

Here is the content of the docker-compose logs command:

gcs_sync           | ERROR: gcloud crashed (TransportError): HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f78ad0b7d90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again'))

I have tried using the host network but I don't know how to connect to it, I get the

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, with docker 3.7, you can add `networking_mode: host`:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  gcs_sync:
    image: gcs-sync:latest
    container_name: gcs_sync
    networking_mode: host
    environment:
      PLUGIN_BUCKET: bucket
      PLUGIN_SOURCE: /
      PLUGIN_TARGET: /mnt/data/google
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_FILE: /mnt/key/cred.json
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /home/ec2-user/data/google
        target: /mnt/data/google
      - type: bind
        source: /home/ec2-user/key
        target: /mnt/key
```