# Ansible unreachable with HTTPSConnectionPool error caused by NewConnectionErrors

Tags: ansible, azure-vm

We are intermittently seeing the below errors while running ansible playbooks on Azure VMs

**fatal: [<< server_name>> ]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ntlm: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<<host_name>>', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9e0b3f7790>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Try again'))", "unreachable": true}**

Strangely it happens on any random servers (we deploy to 7 servers).

Any insights? Or anyone faced with the same challenge.

Below is the ansible information:

```
ansible [core 2.11.1] 
  config file = /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Sandboxes/VinSandbox/TST02-EscherCpxEcpDelivery (R8 AIO Manual)/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, May  6 2021, 00:05:59) [GCC 10.2.1 20201203]
  jinja version = 3.0.1
  libyaml = False
```

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65395192/no-internet-in-docker-container-when-launched-with-docker-compose) matches your experience; are you running that inside of docker?

Comment: Hello, yes, we're running this inside of docker and orchestrated using Aks. Container losing connection is definitely likely.
Thank you

Comment: What happened with this error?, Did you solve it?